# How build a project with platform configuration via devenv.exe\com?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, devenv

I am trying to build a solution via devenv.com and I get errors. The command I use:

```
set devenvCom=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com  
"%devenvCom%" "C:\...\mySolution.sln" /Build "Release|AnyCPU"
```

I get an error: **"The operation could not be completed"**
But if I run it without a platform configuration:

```
set devenvCom=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com  
"%devenvCom%" "C:\...\mySolution.sln" /Build "Release"
```

This works fine.

But in their documentation they say that you can use the format: `/Build "Release|AnyCPU"`
And it doesn't matter if Irun the command using devenv.exe or devenv.com they both fail.

How can I run the command successfuly?

Comment: This seems very counter-intuitive and unnecessary.  What do you hope to achieve by manually setting up the build information instead of just using the built-in `Build...` option (F5)?

Comment: I am attempting to build the solution offline. And I want to control the platform I am building and transfer that as a parameter to the command. Once I get it to work

Comment: You don't need to be online to use the `Build...` option.  And iirc there's a menu in the `Build` tab that allows you to edit the parameters for the build.

Comment: Yeah but what if you want to build offline in multiple platforms one by one in a batch without opening the GUI and setting the build configuration manually? I mean once you build in "Win32" then "x64" etc..

Comment: Using either method, you'd still have to build, move the executable and its dependencies, and then change the settings manually.

Comment: You are missing the idea. I want the build to be automatic and test my solution with both configuration over night and give me logs. I don't want to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have in both of your commands - with and without platform - is correct for **devenv.com** in Visual Studio 2017, according to Microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2017.

I run similar commands with **devenv.com** in VS2019 without any difficulty, via a batch file run as part of a Jenkins job.

The following notes may assist in resolving this issue:

When defining environment variables for file or folder paths, I suggest using double quotes as follows:

```
set "devenvCom=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com"
```

These double quotes make it easier to ensure you have not added any trailing whitespace to the environment variable value by mistake.   The double quotes also ensure that any parentheses or ampersands in the path will not be misinterpreted by the **cmd.exe** shell.

It is fine to double quote the parameter which follows **/Build**, e.g. **/Build "Release"**.  These double quotes are REQUIRED when specifying the platform such as **/Build "Release|AnyCPU"**, to ensure the vertical bar is not misinterpreted by the **cmd.exe** shell, or when the build configuration name contains a space.

I recommend **/Rebuild** rather than **/Build** when performing automated builds.  Only the former is guaranteed to perform a complete build from scratch.

[Microsoft documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2017) "Insert one space character between switches and arguments on the same line", i.e. put ONE SPACE between the **/Build** parameter and the value which follows it, e.g. **"Release|AnyCPU"**.

The name of the build configuration and platform, e.g. **"Release|AnyCPU"**, is expected to be found in the specified solution file.  These *solution* build configurations names and platforms do not have to correspond to the *project* build configuration names and platforms (though they should whenever possible).

If you wish to build *a single project only*, I have been successful with the following syntax in VS2019:

```
"%devenvCom%" "C:\...\myProject.vcxproj" /Build "Release|AnyCPU" /Project "myProject"
```

Note that the first parameter in the above example is a *project file*, rather than a solution file.  I believe that the specified build configuration and platform refer to the *project* rather than the unspecified *solution* (note: Visual Studio may create a temporary solution when performing single project builds if it cannot find a solution that corresponds to the specified project).

For single project builds, I previously had success specifying the solution file first, and the project file after **/Project**, but this previous syntax does not consistently succeed in VS2019 build 16.11.2 - it can lead to **devenv.exe** remaining running indefinitely after the project builds successfully (**devenv.exe** gets launched by **devenv.com**).

Your VS2017 installation may be corrupt, or you may have an extension that is interfering with VS2017.